# stop user from zooming out from zoom level 15 maps v2 android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to set min zoom level to be 15 and user cannot zoom out of that level but he can zoom into 20 .

So throughout the app the user can use zoom enabled(true) but cannot go out of zoom level 15.Should I disable zoom afte 15 ? but that would even disable zoom in .
I dont know how to manage onl one condition in this case .How do I do it.I really appreciate any help.
Thanks in Advance

```
public OnCameraChangeListener getCameraChangeListener()
{
    return new OnCameraChangeListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) 
        {
            Log.d("Zoom", "Zoom: " + position.zoom);

            if(previousZoomLevel != position.zoom)
            {
                isZooming = true;

                if(zoomscale==15){

        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);

               googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);


                       }

            }

            previousZoomLevel = position.zoom;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Post some code which you have tried up till now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of current version (3.2.65) there is no API for setting min/max zoom level.
Hopefully there will be in the future, as this is already requested on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4663).

Anyway there is a way to handle it nicely in your own code: in `onCameraChange` if zoom is smaller than 15, call `GoogleMap.animateCamera` back to zoom 15. It will not stop the user from zooming out to see the whole world, but it will start zooming in after user finishes doing what they feel like doing. It will look similar to this: http://youtube.com/watch?v=-nCZ37HdheY (not only zoom, but also position is "corrected").

Comment: how do I do that and what time interval will map get back to 15 ?

Answer (score 2):

## Try this

- This won't allow the user to zoom out after the given zoom level.
- `mMap.setMinZoomPreference(float yourDesiredLevel)`;